# Google Sheets: Perform a running formula in the same column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple formula I want to perform in the same column.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BgpMDwY8zfChNNS9MDnHItmBTyVZkgYSC_kA42ofMaY/edit?usp=sharing)

Column A: dates

Column C: multiplier

Column B: where I want to perform the formula.

B2 = B1-B1*$C$1

B3 = B2-B2*$C$1 etc

I'd like to automatically run the formula as the number of months (in Col A) changes.

| ​A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/22 | 100 | 0.5 |
| 1/5/22 | 50 |  |
| 1/6/22 | 25 |  |

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,B1*C1^SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Works well but doesn't do what's needed as the multiplier in C1 changes and so I need to reuse the result of the calculation from the previous cell.

Comment: @JeyJay functionality you describe is possible to achieve only by script. gs formulae do not remember "past states" they recalculate on every change

Comment: Ok thanks @player0
Someone found a solution but it won't work for every situation:
=arrayformula( B1 * (1 - C1) ^ sequence(count(A2:A)) )

Answer (score 0):

=arrayformula( B1 * (1 - C1) ^ sequence(count(A2:A)) )